# SQL taking too much time for executing a query

Tags: sql-server

i am using below query to generate some information of around 7k lines. but the issue is that the query is taking too much time to complete just 7k line. i need to fine tune it.

```
select mo.CardUId,mo.CarParkUId,mo.PersonUId,mo.CardType,mo.CardNr,pk.LastName            company_name,ab.Name carpark_name,
mo.ValidFrom,mo.ValidUntil,mo.LastTccTime,p.LastName    customerName,mo.GroupName, mo.Name,p.Type,
mo.LastTccNr,mo.DisplayableCardCarrierNrId serialnr,mo.BlacklistEntry,

mo.GroupNumber from Person p


LEFT outer join vwAllCards mo on p.PersonUId=mo.PersonUId
left outer join Person pk on pk.PersonUId=p.CompanyDepartmentUId
left outer join CarPark ab on ab.CarParkUId=mo.CarParkUId
where p.Type=0 and mo.Name is not null
order by p.LastName
```

Comment: You can use the profiler to auto tune it. Have you already done it?

Comment: Do you use any indexes? Have you checked the explain plan?

Comment: no, i have not.

Comment: What is slow: select or insert? Actual execution plan is needed anyway.

Comment: Maybe you need to check the fragmentation of your indexes and rebuild them. Believe me, it can have a huge negative impact if your indexes are fragmented.

Comment: Execute the query again with "Include Actual Execution Plan" option. Once the query finished executing, go to the "Execution Plan" tab, copy the XML and paste in https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ (and submit) and provide us the link here to examine the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the SQL Profiler to auto create the indexes needed for a fine tune query.

- Enter in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) -> Tools -> SQL Server Profiler.
- Click Connect, and then click Run, to start a new trace.
- Execute your slow query now, so the profiler can capture and record it.
- Stop the query and File -> Save it.
- In the menu, click Tools -> Database Engine Tuning advisor.
- Click Connect when it opens, and in Workload, select file, and click the first button on the right (binoculars one). Then select the file you have just saved.
- Select now the checkbox of your database, and click the "Start Analysis" button (below the "View" and "Action" menu).
- Once it finish, open "Action" menu, and click in "Apply Recommendations".

Now you should have a fast and fine tuned query.

Comment: This is good advice, but please make sure that you do not just automatically apply whatever is recommended by the Index Tuning Wizard (or whatever name it goes by nowadays). The main issue is that it will suggest indexing for whatever specific query you just had it analyze, without taking into consideration any other queries that might be accessing the same table(s). You ideally would always scrutinize the suggestion to ensure it makes sense for your actual setup.

Answer (score -2):

use with (nolock)

mo.GroupNumber from Person p with (nolock)