# how to speed up trigger

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have 800 records in a table, I used trigger to update more than 20 fields from 4 tables but very slow takes up to 25 sec to update changes, i know computed fields are faster but i cant use computed fields to get/ update fields data from another table. what other methods can i use?

below i tried to show is how i am trying to updating field

```
create  TRIGGER [dbo].[WO-WHLINFO] 
    ON [dbo].[WORKORDERS]
    AFTER  INSERT,UPDATE
    AS 
    BEGIN    IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
     RETURN      UPDATE T1 
         SET  [C/S ANGLE2]=T2.[C/S ANGLE2], 
              [BH SIZE2]=T2.[BH SIZE2],
              [COLOR]=T2.[COLOR], 
              [MRP Wheel]=T2.[STOCK NO],    
              [WO PN]=T2.[WHL-ASSY LOOKUP]

          FROM WORKORDERS T1 CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
             FROM [WHl] T2
             WHERE [WHEEL PN 1]=T2.[WHL-ASSY LOOKUP] OR 
                   [WHEEL PN 1-S]= T2.[STOCK NO]) T2
             END
```

what other options i can use to update field data from another table?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42780910/sql-taking-too-much-time-for-executing-a-query/42781448#42781448. It seems you have a missing index

Comment: Thank you Carlos but i can use Database Engine Tuning advisor. because i have express edition

Comment: Most triggers have at least one reference to `inserted` or `deleted` rows.

Comment: @HBO Thank you can you explain me more i don't quite get it

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables) article provides some explanation of how to use the `inserted` and `deleted` tables to determine which rows were affected by the triggering SQL statement. Your `update` statement doesn't limit the processing to only the rows that have been changed by the SQL statement that caused the trigger to fire.

Comment: Thank you @HABO i will take a look at it

Comment: @Joe You can view missing index details by showing the execution plans while running your queries in smss Express versions.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to create index on table,this may increase the speed of insertion and deletion

Comment: with which column name or how can i select column to apply index? Composite index to all column doesn't affect anything?

Comment: I CREATED index using the Pk's as `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [speedup_trigger] ON [dbo].[WORKORDERS]
(
 [PO #] ASC,
 [WORK ORDER #] ASC,
 [CUSTOMER] ASC,
 [SO NUMBER] ASC,
 [SO DATE] ASC,
 [PROMISED DATE] ASC,
 [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO` but nothing chnaged