# SQL join running slow

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 sql queries doing the same thing, first query takes 13 sec to execute while second takes 1 sec to execute. Any reason why ?

Not necessary all the ids in ProcessMessages will have data in ProcessMessageDetails

-- takes 13 sec to execute

```
 Select  * from dbo.ProcessMessages t1
   join dbo.ProcessMessageDetails t2 on t1.ProcessMessageId = t2.ProcessMessageId
    Where Id = 4 and Isdone = 0
```

--takes under a sec to execute

```
   Select * from dbo.ProcessMessageDetails
    where ProcessMessageId in ( Select  distinct ProcessMessageId  from dbo.ProcessMessages t1
    Where  Where Id = 4 and Isdone = 0 )
```

I have clusterd index on t1.processMessageId(Pk) and non clusterd index on t2.processMessageId (FK)

Comment: from what tables are id and isdone sourced?  Additinoally in the 1st one you have a 1-M join being resolved while in teh 2nd the engine doesn't have to join the tables.

Comment: Id and Isdone is sourced from dbo.ProcessMessages t1. I have created a non clustered index for Id and IsDone

Comment: Can you add execution plan?

Comment: Have you looked at your execution plan for both queries to see the difference?

Comment: Share both query plans please.

Comment: If I had to guess, in the first one, the engine is joining the records first, then having to throw away many of the records since the ID <> 4 and isdone <> 0.  In the second query, you're limiting to a small subset to filter by.  Out of curiosity if you change `where` to `AND` on the first  query do you get a performance gain?  but plan would help.

Comment: For starters, the second query only shows the contents of `dbo.ProcessMessageDetails`, where the first query shows the contents of both tables. Why are you doing a `LEFT JOIN` on the first query and an `INNER JOIN` theoretically on the second.

Comment: Updated the query to inner join

Comment: @user1005310 `join` is the same as `inner join`

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42780910/sql-taking-too-much-time-for-executing-a-query/42781448#42781448

Answer (score 1):

I would need the actual execution plans to tell you exactly what SqlServer is doing behind the scenes. I can tell you these queries aren't doing the exact same thing.

The first query is going through and finding all of the items that meet the conditions for t1 and finding all of the items for t2 and then finding which ones match and joining them together.

The second one is saying first find all of the items that are meet my criteria from t1, and then find the items in t2 that have one of these IDs.

Depending on your statistics, available indexes, hardware, table sizes: Sql Server may decide to do different types of scans or seeks to pick data for each part of the query, and it also may decide to join together data in a certain way.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is really simple the first query which have used will generate more number of rows as compared to the second query so it will take more time to search those many rows that's the reason your first query took 13 seconds and the second one to only one second

So it is generally suggested that you should apply your conditions before making your join or else your number of rows will increase and then you will require more time to search those many rows when joined.