# Select count Distinct Slow MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-execution-plan

Hello I got a simple query here but its slow as hell, takes around 40sec to get data back, I tried different SQL but still can't seem to make it work, any suggestions would be grateful

```
select
  count (Distinct s.ExternalCustomerID) as PlayerCount,
  s.League  as Extra
from Q_Net_Ml_SportsDetailsActivity_monthly s with (nolock)
where  s.MerchantID = 584
  and s.WagerCount > 0
  and s.Year = 2021
group by League
```

Plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJ1bL0ivY

I tried this: subquery

```
SELECT
    COUNT(ExternalCustomerID) AS Playercount,
    League AS extra
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      ExternalCustomerID,
      League
    FROM Q_Net_Ml_SportsDetailsActivity_monthly s with (nolock, INDEX(NCSI_Q_Net_Ml_SportsDetailsActivity_monthly))
    Where  s.MerchantID = 584
      and s.WagerCount > 0
      and s.Year = 2021
) dt
GROUP BY League
```

still seems slow
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkAHjCswY

Comment: `NOLOCK` is not a go-faster switch, it's an incorrect-results switch, don't use it unless you really know what you're doing. Please add index definitions to your query. At a guess, you need an index `(MerchantID, Year, League, ExternalCustomerID) INCLUDE (WagerCount )` but it's hard to say for sure

Comment: @HoneyBadger I think they are: the first query returns the count of distinct `ExternalCustomerID` **per `League`**, the second makes up a list of distinct pairs first, then does the same count **per `League`**

Comment: Maybe this is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42780910/sql-taking-too-much-time-for-executing-a-query/42781448#42781448

Answer (score -1):

Probably try to put some indexes in your table 'Q_Net_Ml_SportsDetailsActivity_monthly', in columns that are used in select statements. Then try to run the query again.

Comment: Added new index on Test side does seem quicker, I will add to production side see if makes difference, we using column store indexes and usually not really need other indexes

Comment: What index? Like a covering index on `(MerchantID, Year, Wager) INCLUDE (...)`?

Comment: CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_Q_Net_Ml_SportsDetailsActivity_monthly_3] ON [dbo].[Q_Net_Ml_SportsDetailsActivity_monthly]
(
 MerchantID, Year, League, ExternalCustomerID
) 
    
    INCLUDE (WagerCount )

Comment: applied index on production and still slow is there anything else I can do, I am guessing it's resource issues on azure SQL, we are on HS core 2 and if I do a select all id's there are 33million rows.